# CSS: page cannot scroll all the way to left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Spend hours on this and cannot figure why this is the case. My page just will not scroll all the way to the left. like this:
[image: img]

I think this has to do with using `justify-content: center;` in the css body tag. When I set this to `justify-content: start;` I can scroll to the left, but I want to center my content.

Also, setting `position: absolute` to the css body tag would also fix the problem. But I don't know if I should do that.

Here are my code:
Html:

```
<body>

<div class="mainAppContainer">
    <div class="project">
        <div class="todo">

        </div>

        
        <form id="todoForm">
            <label for="title">
                Title:
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
            </label>
            <label for="description">
                Description:
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </label>
            <label for="dueDate">
                Due Date:
                <input type="date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate">
            </label>
            <label for="priority">
                Priority:
                <select name="priority" id="priority">
                    <option value="High">
                        <div class="block"></div>
                        High
                    </option>
                    <option value="Mid">
                        <div class="block"></div>
                        Mid
                    </option>
                    <option value="Low">
                        <div class="block"></div>
                        Low
                    </option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <button>Add</button>
        </form>
        <button id="addTodoButton">+Todo</button>
    </div>
    
    <button id="addProjectButton">+Project</button>
    <button id="addProjectButton">+Project</button>
    <button id="addProjectButton">+Project</button>

</div>
```

and css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}


.mainAppContainer {
    background-color: white;

    min-height: 1000px;
    width: auto;
   
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;


    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 350px;
    grid-gap: 20px;

    
}

#addProjectButton {
    background-color: rgb(162, 232, 255);
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;

}


.project {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(162, 232, 255);
    height: 90%;
    width: 350px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

Comment: Does resizing your browser window change how your page is displayed? I suspect somewhere it's overflowing because the flex items have a set width. If you open your page on a screen wide enough to contain everything, does it still have the same issue?